# Number of Perfect Powers in Pascal`s Triangle

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

In [Pascal`s Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), let the number of perfect powers and $1$ between the first row and $n$th row be $f(n)$.

What is the value of $f(100)$?

While it can no doubt be done with a calculator, but is there no other way to calculate $f(100)$?

The first initial values for $f(n)$ are $1,3,5,7,11,13,15,17,21,27,29,...$

The problem proved quite difficult, as it is difficult to predict if $\binom{n}{m}$ is a perfect power. How can we calculate $f(n)$ for any large value of $n$?

It seems like that $f(n)-f(n-1) \le 6$ for small values of $n$, but I think that for some large $n$, $f(n)-f(n-1) \ge 6$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well this sequence isn't in oeis (https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C5%2C7%2C11%2C13%2C15%2C17%2C21%2C27%2C29%2C&language=english&go=Search) so an answer might lead to an entry there.

Comment: You seem to count $1 = 1^k$ as a perfect power, but not $k = k^1$ generally of course.  It might be expeditious to exclude the $1$ entries at either end of the rows and $n = \binom{n}{1}$ where row $n$ itself is a power greater than $1$ of an integer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a theorem by Erdős which (partially) solves your problem   :

> **Theorem** .
>   The equation :$$\binom{n}{k}=m^l$$ has no integer solutions with $l \geq 2$ and $4 \leq k \leq n-4$

You can find a proof in **Proofs from the BOOK** or directly in Erdős's paper here http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1951-05.pdf

This means that on a row , $n$ there are at most $8$ perfect powers and so : $$f(n)-f(n-1) \leq 8$$

It seems plausible that $f(n)-f(n-1) \leq 6$ but this would mean to prove that $\binom{n}{1}$ , $\binom{n}{2}$  ,$\binom{n}{3}$ can't be perfect powers simultaneously (and I don't know how to do this).

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot access the link.